# USA - Combining business with pleasure

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, business-travel

I will soon be going on a business trip to USA. I will be travelling on a B1 visa. My business will be for 4 weeks there. I would like to spend a week after I conclude my business, with my sister, who lives in US.

For some context, I have been on 3 business trips on the same visa earlier.

My employer's invite letter expects me to provide the exact dates for From and To and the duration. I'm bit confused about what I should mention. Should I mention the 4 weeks that are strictly business, or 5 weeks of my total duration in US? My employer pays me for accommodation, per diem only for the 4 weeks of my trip. This is also mentioned in the letter, apparently.

Will 5 weeks be considered too long for a business trip? In the past, I have always been given a 6 months duration in my I-94. My last trip was in 2011. Not sure if the immigration screenings have become strict since then.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your visa is "B1", rather than "B1/B2"? They are usually issued as "B1/B2" which allows both business and tourism. In rare cases pure "B1" visas can be issued, though (see [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21730/does-the-us-currently-issue-independent-b1-or-b2-visas-or-only-the-combined-b1)), and if you have one of those, you're not supposed to include any pleasure travel.

Comment: Thanks. It is B1/B2. I'm also more confused about whether to include the entire 5 weeks in the invite letter or just the 4 weeks.

Comment: If you already have your visa, what paperwork are you worried about dates of travel for?

Comment: CGCampbell: For a business trip, sometimes immigration officials do ask for an official invite letter. The letter usually provides information about the company, designation, purpose of the traveler. It is usually advised to carry this letter. I have been asked about this only once in my 4 trips so far.

Answer (score 5):

First rule of dealing with immigration officers: never lie. Never, ever, ever lie. When applying for the visa, include the invitation letter and add that you want spend one more week. Same at the border. It's perfectly normal and understandable that you want to spend a week on holiday after a business trip. I can't even count how many times I answered to the border official "both" when asked this question -- I am going to the conference and visiting friends. It's fine.

Comment: The visa is already applied for and issued, as far as I read the question.

Comment: "Should I mention the 4 weeks that are strictly business, or 5 weeks of my total duration in US?" I answered this one with personal experience. I will edit to make this more clear.

Comment: @chx, Thanks. I already have a visa and have traveled with it multiple times. This is the first time when I'm extending my stay for a week, for pleasure.