# Is a B2 visa application OK for a scientific conference?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, b1-b2-visas, applications

Background:
I am a PhD student. I intend to attend a scientific conference in the US in August, where I'll be presenting a paper. I specified B-2 type (tourism, pleasure, visit type) while filling my DS-160 application form and scheduling an appointment with the US Embassy in Madrid. I later realized that B-1 (business type) fits better for scientific conferences, but I had already submitted the DS-160 form with B-2 specified on it before realizing. I have also received an appointment confirmation.

Question:
Do you think specifying B-2 instead of B-1 might be a problem during the visa interview please? What can I do to avoid potential problems please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you need a visa at all? If you're a Spanish citizen, you can attend the conference on the Visa Waiver Program.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not Spanish, but I have a Schengen visa with Spain as port of entry.

Comment: Follow-up: I got the B1/B2 visa without any problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up - very useful for those with similar questions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, not a problem. The interviewer will ask you about the reasons of visiting, and will correct the visa type on the spot if you chose the wrong type. One time, I was applying for D visa (crew visa), and I asked the interviewer if it's ok to include another visa as well (B1/B2), he asked me why and I told him I would like to visit if I have some days off, he said ok and I got it.

Regarding B1/B2, most likely you will get the two together, [it's rare to issue just one of the two B visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21739/10051).

Comment: Thanks a lot Heidel Ber Gensis! Your response has helped to put my mind at rest :)

Comment: @rand0muzr it would be nice and more helpful to come back and update us with the outcome after the interview..

Comment: Sure, I will do so.