# Can I still change my B1 visa application to B1/B2 before the interview

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I want to change my B1 Visa application to B1/B2 Visa before the interview. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: You can even mention it *in* your interview. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/71990/19400.

Answer (score 8):

You won't need to.

A large majority ([about 98 percent](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21739/16947)) of visitor visas to the USA are issued as combined B-1/B-2 no matter whether the applicant specified business or tourism in the application.

If you end up getting a B-1 visa only, it will be because there are particular circumstances to your application that give them cause to *deliberately* select the restricted kind of visa. In that case an application for a combined B-1/B-2 visa probably wouldn't have been successful anyway.

---

Note that if you have a *single trip* that combines business and tourism activities, then this is allowed even on a pure B-1 visa. There is no combined B-1/B-2 immigration *status* anyway, so business travelers arriving on a B-1/B-2 visa will be *admitted* in B-1 status. And even the immigration police does not require that business visitors refrain from enjoying themselves during their trip.

[USCIS says](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status):

> You do not need to apply to change your nonimmigrant status if you were admitted into the U.S. for business reasons (B-1 visa category) and you wish to remain for pleasure before your authorized stay expires.

The only situation in which you **need** a B-1/B-2 visa specifically is if you want to use the *same visa* for *different trips*, of which some are business and other are purely tourism.