# Received a different US visa category than I applied for

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I am from germany and an employee of a large US-based IT company. I recently applied for a B1/B2 and I went through the whole process. I then went to the consulate last week and they accepted my application and told me that they would ship my passport to me as I ordered.
I just received my passport via the mail but when I checked everything, I noticed that instead of B1/B2 the visa only states B1. Is this just a human error or is there more to it? And most importantly, is there anything I can/should do about this to change it to a B1/B2 and how long would this take?

Comment: I know, I am going on a business trip but because I also planned to stay longer and do some tourism things. Thats why I applied for the B1/B2

Comment: It is quite unusual because they default to providing B1/B2 even when you apply or only B1 or only B2

Comment: This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21739/4188) shows how unusual.

Comment: https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/NIVWorkload/FY2018NIVWorkloadbyVisaCategory.pdf

Comment: @user56513 it may not be unusual at all depending on the applicant's nationality.  Phill, what is your nationality?

Comment: @phoog Only Burma and Oman have B1 or B2 visas anywhere near close to or more than the B1/B2 visas issued.

Comment: @phoog I am german, so I don't see any problems there

Comment: It's a bit odd for a German national to apply for a visa when it's not required (unless you intend to stay longer than 90 days).

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's why I applied for it, I will be staying over 90 days. Otherwise I would have gone with ESTA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/81016/4188) is helpful, let me repost the relevant parts.

[USCIS](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/change-my-nonimmigrant-status-category/change-my-nonimmigrant-status) says:

> You do not need to apply to change your nonimmigrant status if you were admitted into the United States for business reasons (B-1 visa category ) and you wish to remain in the United States for pleasure before your authorized stay expires.

The only situation in which you need a B-1/B-2 visa specifically is if you want to use the same visa for different trips, of which some are business and other are purely tourism.