# Tourist or business US visa if visiting for a company's meeting

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, romanian-citizens

Can you kindly please advise me on what type of visa - B1 or B2 (business or tourist) would I need to apply for?

To give you some context:

I am currently working for a US company in London - cover the EMEA region. The company is organising a global meeting in the US where all company members need to attend.

My questions is, would I need a business visa or a tourist visa? My company can show all details of travel etc.

PS: I am a Romanian citizen who has been living and working in London for the last past 6 years.

Answer (score 5):

Simple: You're going for business, so you need a **business** (B1) visa.  Attending a company meeting is a perfect example of a valid business need.

However, the US [most commonly issues the combined B1/B2 visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21730/does-the-us-currently-issue-independent-b1-or-b2-visas-or-only-the-combined-b1?rq=1), which is valid for either purpose, and you'll most likely get one of these if you apply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Have a great weekend!

Comment: Please accept it (click on the check mark) if it was helpful!