# Should I apply for both B1 and B2 visas or only for a B1 visa for business and tourism purposes?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas, business-travel

I want to use my annual vacation to attend a seminar in the US. Should I apply for a B1 (business) visa only, or for both B1 and B2 (tourist) visas?

Thanks for your support through your answers.

Answer (score 5):

As outlined in the statistics in a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21739/9009), 97% of all B visas issued by US consulates are B1/B2 visas. Therefore you are likely to receive a B1/B2 visa even if you only apply for a B1 visa.

Personally I would select the B1/B2 option on the DS-160 form - just be prepared to explain what kind of tourist activities you're conceiving in the future. They don't have to be concrete plans, something like "I want to visit NYC next summer" would be sufficient.

Comment: Even "I'm thinking about visiting the US at some point in the next few years" would probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you go for B1/B2. My reasons are:

1. It does not take more than what is required to apply for the B1
2. With the same cost of application, you get both B1 and B2
3. In future, if you need to visit the USA for non-business purpose, you will have the advantage of the B2
4. It's preferable to have the B2 along with the B1

PS: You cannot use B1 for tourism purpose. When you travel on the B1, you have to carry an invitation from the concerned parties and businesses with whom you are going to work in the USA.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me Anand. Of course it help me a lot. now I know that I should apply B1/B2 visa. good day!!