# Software engineer from India, planning to visit the USA for 3-4 weeks for pleasure. Which visa should I apply for?

Tags: visas, usa, india, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas

I see 3 options: B1, B2, B1/B2.

This is purely a personal trip and I am visiting my friend. I would like to roam around. Documents say I should apply for B2.

But I would like to use the same visa if I could get any offer from my company to visit the USA for business conferences or short trips in the future.

Can I apply for a B1/B2 and get it? Or should I apply only for a B2?

Comment: Most of the time they'll give you a B1/B2 regardless of which you apply for. Refer this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/can-i-use-b1-b2-visa-to-travel-to-the-us-without-a-business-purpose and this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21730/does-the-us-currently-issue-independent-b1-or-b2-visas-or-only-the-combined-b1

Comment: Thanks much for your instant reply. So, i can apply B1/B2 in the website and can support my decision for applying B1/B2 by saying i may in future can get a business requirement from my company and this Visa should help me in avoiding applying for another visa for B1.   I am much worried about the questions i face at interview . I want to save money and Efforts in applying for another business visa.

Answer (score 5):

Just apply for the B2. Explain that you just want to travel for tourism and are visiting friends.

The officer at the embassy will decide if you qualify for B2 or B1/B2; 9/10 if you apply for B2 or B1, you get B1/B2.

Don't apply for B1/B2 and then in the interview say "in case in the future..." this is surely going to get you rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Apply for B2, though they give B1/B2 combined but you have to justify the first visit during the interview with the consulate officer. If you pitch in the thought about business visit in the future, be ready for serious questioning you might be uncomfortable answering.